# Trouble With Sign In GUI

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Every Time I run the following code I receive an error, can anyone help?
There may be other errors in the code, please help me fix those too.

```
from tkinter import *

class Custom_Button():

    users = [("bobbymartin", "*****"), ("goodday", "*****")]

    def sign_in():
        for(username, password) in users:
            if ent_username.get() == username and password:
                print("Login Successful")

    def Display(Label, Entry, Button, sys):

        root = Tk()
        root.title("Binary Suite")
        lab_username = Label(root, text="Username")
        lab_username.grid(row=0, column=0)
        lab_password = Label(root, text="Password")
        lab_password.grid(row=0, column=0)
        ent_username = Entry(root)
        ent_username.grid(row=0, column=1)
        ent_password = Entry(root)
        ent_password.grid(row=0, column=1)
        but_signin = Button(root, text="Sign In", command=sign_in)
        but_signin.pack(side=LEFT)
        but_quit = Button(root, text="Quit", command=sys.quit)
        but_quit.pack(side=RIGHT)

        root.mainloop()

    Display(Label, Entry, Button, sys)

Custom_Button()
```

Here is the error that I recieve.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\Custom Widgets.py", line 3, in <module>
    class Custom_Button():
  File "C:\Users\...\Custom Widgets.py", line 31, in Custom_Button
    Display(Label, Entry, Button, sys)
  File "C:\Users\...\Custom Widgets.py", line 24, in Display
    but_signin = Button(root, text="Sign In", command=sign_in)
NameError: global name 'sign_in' is not defined
```

**Edit:** Removed passwords from list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sign_in` is not defined. Because this is a class definition you need to use `self.sign_in`

Comment: when I try to use self EX: def Display(..., self) it says self is undefined.:[

Comment: @LaneSurface: `self` needs to be the first argument of both `sign_in` and `Display`. Though, the problems of your code go a little deeper than that. You should probably start with a tutorial on how to use python classes.